# Error al pasar parametros Java-Python (Jython)

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jython

Tengo que pasar 3 parametros de java a python, tengo entendido que si encuentra el file.py pero tiene un problema al momento de leer los datos:

```
Java -> Model.java

public void callPython(String user_ciclos, String temp_min, String temp_max)
    {
        interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.exec("from Arduino import sendData");
        PyObject func = interpreter.get("sendData");
        func.__call__(new PyString(user_ciclos), new PyString(temp_min), new PyString(temp_max));
    }
```

```
Python -> Arduino.py

def sendData(ciclos, tem_m, temp_max):
    print(ciclos, tem_m, temp_max)
    '''
    ardu= serial.Serial('COM4',9600, timeout=.1)
    time.sleep(1)
    ardu.write(ciclos.encode())
    ardu.write(temp_m.encode())
    ardu.write(temp_max.encode())
    time.sleep(1)
    '''



sendData(sys.argv[0],sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Niveles de archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Error en texto:
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.python.core.PySystemState (file:/C:/Jython/jython.jar) to method java.io.Console.encoding()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.python.core.PySystemState
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
console: Failed to install '': java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: cp0.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "__pyclasspath__/Arduino.py", line 24, in <module>
IndexError: index out of range: 1
```

Update:

```
Como uso el IDE Eclipse, es necesario cambiar el tipo de encodificación a UTF-8:
1.- Window
  -> Preferences
2.- General
  -> Workspace
  -> Text File encoding
```

Comment: Hola Axel, ¿Cuál es el error exactamente?

Comment: Una disculpa, acabo de actualizar la publicacion añadiendo el errror

Comment: puedes poner el error como texto? No todo le mundo tiene capacidad de ver las imágenes o algunos las tienen bloqueado por el proxy empresarial

Comment: También hallé esto: https://bugs.jython.org/issue2222

Comment: @RuslanLópez Leere acerca de eso, muchas gracias y ya añadi el error como texto, una disculpa

Answer (score 1):

Como uso el IDE Eclipse, es necesario cambiar el tipo de encodificación a UTF-8:

```
1.- Window
  -> Preferences
2.- General
  -> Workspace
  -> Text File encoding
```